# ajax success callback not working on json response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

AJAX request was successfully sent to php server and also inserted records on my oracle database. I cannot get the JSON response in success, error, complete callback functions.

I can't also see any logs on console.log

I am using codeigniter and my php server was on model folder and it returns an json formatted string.

```
echo json_encode(array("Response"=>99,"Value"=> $result));
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/functionhere',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "STUDID": studId,
            "LASTNAME": lastName,
            "FIRSTNAME": firstName,
            "MIDINITIAL": midInitial,
            "BIRTHDAY": birthday,
            "AGE": age,
            "GENDER": 'M'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Response == 99) {
            alert(data.Value);
            console.log("putek");
        }
    },
    error: function (header, status, error) {
        console.log('ajax answer post returned error ' + header + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);

    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("putek");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using IE? It can be funny with console.log(). You have to solve that before you can troubleshoot.

Comment: Try to use console.log(data) before your `if` statement in your success method.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say? And the Net tab?

Comment: @Vadorequest But then anyway complete callback should be fired. For sure, i'm not sure how OP is debugging it

Comment: Try a simple `alert('success');` before the `if` in your success function to see if it is firing at all. If your `if` check is failing, you'll never see your current alert.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, but his code could work and the success could be fired and he doesn't know it because the code in the if could be not executed. Maybe the condition is false, who knows. To debug it's better to not be inside a condition, especially if you're not sure the function is fired.

Comment: @Vadorequest But then complete would be fired anyway: `complete: function () {
        console.log("putek");
    }`

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right. I guess, I never used complete but it makes sense that its always called when the request is complete. But when the request is complete? When a response is returned, isn't? Maybe he doesn't get anything because the server doesn't respond nything and the client script is still waiting and doesn't fire neither success/error/complete while the timeout isn't reached.

Comment: @CollinGrady I already tried a simple alert('success') but still wont work

Answer (score 1):

Set content type in your PHP file:

```
@header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( array( "Response" => 99, "Value" => $result ) );
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to give this a try (using  jQuery 1.9.1):

```
 var args=new Object();
 args["STUDID"]=studId;
 args["LASTNAME"]=lastName;
 args["FIRSTNAME"]=firstName;
 args["MIDINITIAL"]=midInitial;
 args["BIRTHDAY"]=birthday;
 args["AGE"]=age;
 args["GENDER"]='M';

 $.post("url/goes/here", args)
 .done(function(returnVal){
     var returnObj = $.parseJSON(returnVal);
     //remaining success code goes here
 })
 .fail(function(){
     //put failure code here
 });
```

Comment: As I recall `parseJSON` is used to convert string to JSON object, not for converting JSON object to JSON object? PHP code from server is returning JSON object.

Comment: Hi Prateek. The PHP code, json_encode(), converts a value into its JSON representation (a JSON string). This string is what's returned to the JavaScript AJAX call. From there, jQuery converts the string into a JSON object.

Comment: Now this is enlightening, just went through official documentation of `json_encode`, and as a matter of fact, I've used thousand of places output of json_encode without using `parseJSON()`, never ran into any problem. But surely I was wrong, though thanks! :)